# I get the DateTime constructor's ArgumentOutOfRangeException when checking IsDBNull

Tags: c#, .net, exception, null, odbc

I have a ODBC data source, one of the columns is a DateTime. If I attempt to do anything with the field (`IsDbNull`,`GetValue`,`GetValues`) I will get an exception if the value is this databases equivalent of null.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurred
  HResult=-2146233086
  Message=Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.DateTime.DateToTicks(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day)
       at System.DateTime..ctor(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute, Int32 second)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbBuffer.ReadDateTime(Int32 offset)
       at System.Data.Odbc.CNativeBuffer.MarshalToManaged(Int32 offset, SQL_C sqlctype, Int32 cb)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.internalGetDateTime(Int32 i)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i, TypeMap typemap)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.IsDBNull(Int32 i)
       at Sandbox_Form.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\Code\Sandbox Form\Form1.cs:line 49
  InnerException:
```

If I change my query to `select cast(First_Visit as varchar) as First_Visit_cast from Clients` I get the text string `0/0/0 12:00:00` returned as the result.

Here is the snippet of my testing code. The first 17 rows work fine, however row 18 has that "null" valued date and throws the displayed exceptions.

```
const string Query = @"select cast(First_Visit as varchar) as First_Visit_cast
                             ,First_Visit 
                       from Clients";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var con = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=My_ODBC_DSN"))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand(Query, con))
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                var test = rdr.GetValue(0); //returns "0/0/0 12:00:00" as string.

                var test3 = rdr.IsDBNull(1); //Throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime."

                var test2 = rdr.GetValue(1); //Throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime."

                var records = new object[rdr.FieldCount];
                rdr.GetValues(records); //Throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to work around this? I really want to just write my query as `Select * from TableName` instead of identifying all of the DateTimes and explicitly casting them as strings.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum value for DateTime is [Jan 1 0001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx). Your value is less then that, so you get an exception during parsing.

Your value is not null, but it is not a valid .Net DateTime either.

You can write nulls to this field in db instead of "0/0/0 12:00:00"

And if you can't change the datasouce you can make a workaround on your side:

```
object MyGetValue(int i)
{

  if(rdr.GetFieldType(i) == typof(DateTime))
  {
    try{
       return rdr.GetValue(i);
    }
    catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {
     return null;
    }
  }

  return rdr.GetValue(i); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I already know exactly why it is happening. The thing I am having trouble finding is a way to fix the problem. Also to your last edit, I do not have controll of this data source, in fact the prupouse of my program is to export out of this ODBC data source and get it in to a Sql Server database, and I plan on replacing values like this with `NULL`. However `GetValues` throwing a execption when I do `Select * from Foo` is a big problem in my automating of the transfer from this ODBC data-source to SQL Server, I would really appreciate a way to fix the problem.

Comment: Can you fix this data source by running update query that will replace zero dates with something else?

Comment: No, I do not have write access to the data source, nor can I change the behavior of the program that generates the data.

Comment: I was able to send `update Clients set First_visit = NULL where cast(First_visit as varchar) = '0/0/0 12:00:00'` and had 138 updated rows, however I still got `0/0/0 12:00:00` back. It appears that is how the database represents null.

Comment: Hmm, I think that could do it. I would need to override `GetValues` too, but it would work. I am going to try writing up some code and if it works I will give you the answer.